# Fabric js - clipTo SVG failed

Tags: fabricjs

I tried to clip canvas object with fabricjs shape(circle). 
    After applying clipTo, I export canvas to SVG. 
    On SVG i can't get proper clipping result. How can i resolve this.? 
    Please help me. Thanks in advance.

`Image`[image]

`Link :`[http://jsfiddle.net/mullainathan/o9f4dqjn/11/](http://jsfiddle.net/o9f4dqjn/1/)

Comment: Have you able to fix this?

Comment: did you solve the problem? I also came across the same.

Comment: Not yet. Please let me know if you find solution.

Comment: please post the answer if you solved..mine also facing same issue @Mullainathan